# Aws S3 upload with powershell, logging

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need a help to log my script, I have a ps1 script that send my files to s3 bucket, but I need log this script, I try some scripts but not work great.

follow my script working without logging

```
    $region = "us-east-1"
    $folder = "c:\files"
    $bucket = "mybucket"
    $accessKey = "mykey"
    $secretKey = "mysecretkey"
    $server = "testsrv"

    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",$accessKey)
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",$secretKey)
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION",$region)

    aws s3 sync $folder s3://$bucket/$server/
```